# LilyPond: Consistent stem/beam position (not length)

Tags: lilypond

In the style of scottish snare drumming I am trying to notate, the ideal is for all stems and beams to end at the same height.

Unlike concert snare, where all notes are on the line (so this happens implicitly), this notation puts the right hand above the line, and the left hand below. This makes it so that the right handed stems by default end higher than the left handed stems.

For beams, this is easily addressed by `\override Beam.positions = #'(-4 . -4)`. However, this does nothing for the bare stems. Is it possible?

Here is an example showing (1) the beams are good (2) the bare stems are not (3) the music can have grace notes, and they are good as-is.

```
\version "2.22.1"

#(define scottish-snare '(
  (snare          default #f   1)
  (acousticsnare  default #f  -1)
  (sidestick      cross   #f   1)
  (hisidestick    cross   #f  -1)
))
drumPitchNames.rs = #'snare
drumPitchNames.ls = #'acousticsnare
drumPitchNames.rx = #'sidestick
drumPitchNames.lx = #'hisidestick

rflam = #(define-music-function (dur) (ly:duration?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace ls8 rs$dur } #})
lflam = #(define-music-function (dur) (ly:duration?)
  #{ \drummode { \slashedGrace rs8 ls$dur } #})

\drums {
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #(alist->hash-table scottish-snare)
  \override Staff.StaffSymbol.line-count = #1
  \override Beam.positions = #'(-4 . -4)
  \stemDown

  \rflam8 ls8 rs \lflam8 rs4 ls rs8 ls4 rs ls8 \rflam4
}
```